# Get rendered page using JS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="test" value="">
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Get">
</body>
</html>
```

And JS:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
  alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/wuveresele/edit?html,js,output

I want to enter some value (for example, 123) into input field, click button and see "rendered" html code of the page in an alert popup.

What I see:

```
...
<input id="test" value="">
...
```

What I want to see:

```
...
<input id="test" value="123">
...
```

Is it possible using JS or JQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I added to your JS

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $("#test").attr("value",$("#test").val());
  alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
});
```

What I'm essentially doing is using the Jquery [attr() function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).The first parameter refers to the attribute you want to manipulate and the second attribute is the value to be given.

Here is the [working demo](http://jsbin.com/zitadebute/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This is what I'm looking for exactly! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        var value = $("#test").val()
        alert(value);
    });
})
</script>
<input id="test" value="">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Get">
```

Comment: The user wants the data to be visible when the html is printed, so you'll need to use something to set the attribute value to the input value.